# Adapting working Eclipse JDT plugin to Eclipse C++

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I've developed plugin for Eclipse. It includes property page, several actions and specific view. All these features were added by specific extension points:

```
  <page
        class="MyPropertyPage"
        id="MyPage1"
        name="My Project"
        nameFilter="*"
        selectionFilter="single">
     <enabledWhen>
        <instanceof
             value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
        </instanceof> 
     </enabledWhen>   
  </page>           
  <page
        class="MyPropertyPage"
        id="MyPage2"
        name="My Project"
        nameFilter="*"
        selectionFilter="single">
     <enabledWhen>
        <instanceof
             value="org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject">
        </instanceof>                                 
     </enabledWhen>
  </page>
```

The action command class contents code:

```
if (obj instanceof IJavaProject) {
     ...
} else if (obj instanceof CompilationUnit) {
         ...
} else if (obj instanceof TranslationUnit) {
     ...                            
}
```

In debug mode, when the second eclipse is opened with C++ perspective, it works perfectly. But in runtime, it fails with error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/cview/CView`.
The attempt to execute my action command fails as well with similar error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/model/TranslationUnit`.

Help to overcome the error?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you properly set dependencies for your plug-in (Dependencies tab in plugin.xml properties editor)? I'm guessing that would be org.eclipse.cdt.ui.

Comment: org.eclipse.cdt.ui was added to dependencies. May be the order is important? It was the last.

Comment: Don't know. Try moving it up. BTW: How do you install/run your plugin when it fails?

Comment: I've simply copied it to the plugins folder. It works, doesn't it?

Comment: Even for Eclipse C++, my property page works for Navigator view and command runs. For Project Explorer and C/C++ Projects views plugin fails with NoClassDefFoundError exception...

Comment: Copying it into plug-ins should work, provided that the eclipse you are copying it to has the same plug-ins installed as the one you debug it from...